# How do I have the /home directory on a separate drive?

Tags: linux, sd-card, chromebook

I'm planning to install GalliumOS on my Chromebook.  The problem with Chromeboooks is, of course, ha they don't have that much storage on them.  For that reason, I want to tape a 64GB SDXC with UHS-I speeds into the SD slot, to double the amount of storage.

However, I have heard that some people prefer to  have their /home directory on a separate drive.  What are the benefits of this, and how can I set this up on an SDXC card?

Comment: Just format the drive/partition with your required file system and add the mount point in `/etc/fstab` file. "benefits" -- We can do whatever we want :)

Comment: Heads-up: If you place your home directory on an SD card, you should take measures to reduce the number of writes, otherwise the card will wear out pretty fast.

Comment: What do you mean by "wear out?"